# Can't add variable to success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my bit of ajax jquery:..........

```
$(function () {
    $(".follow").click(function () {
        var element = $(this);
        var I = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + I;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "follow.php",
            data: info,
            success: function () {
                $('.follow' + I).fadeOut(200).hide();
                $('.following' + I).fadeIn(200).show();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

my html is:

```
echo "<tr>";

    echo '<td>'. $table["username"]. '</td>'.'<td>'.'<a href="#" id="'.$table['id'].'" class="follow">'.'</a>' . '<a href="#" id="'.$table['id'].'" class="following" style="display:none">'.'</a>' . '</td>';

    echo "<tr>";
```

(which is in a while loop)

On success, I'm trying to fade out the follow button (with its ID) and replace it with a following button with the same ID - However when using (+ I) it doesn't seem to be working?

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is Id gona same for both the links??? **$table['id']**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>It would help if you posted some HTML along with your code for us to get an idea what this should work on.</strike>

Anyhow, from what I see in your code, I *think* it looks something like this:
It seems like my deduced markup was right, your markup boils down to:

```
<a class="follow" id="foobar">Follow</a>
<a class="following" id="foobar">Following</a>
```

If you would want to select the element with class `.following` and ID `foobar`, you'd write `$('#foobar.following')` or `$('.following#foobar')`. So your code would have to be adjusted to:

```
$('.follow#' + I).fadeOut(200).hide();
$('.following#' + I).fadeIn(200).show();
```

However, there is a more fundamental problem with this: IDs uniquely identify an element, which means that **you cannot have two elements with the same ID** on the same page. The HTML above is invalid and the selectors are overqualified with the class selector. A better solution would be to use a `data-` attribute to identify which user the follow/following element belongs to:

```
<a class="follow" data-userid="foobar">Follow</a>
<a class="following" data-userid="foobar">Following</a>
```

You'd then store the data attribute instead of the ID:

```
var I = element.data("userid");
```

and select using the data attribute:

```
$('.follow[data-userid=' + I + ']').fadeOut(200).hide();
$('.following[data-userid=' + I + ']').fadeIn(200).show();
```

As noted before, you don't actually need to select the `.follow` element any more. Just use the `element`!

```
element.fadeOut(200).hide();
$('.following[data-userid=' + I + ']').fadeIn(200).show();
```